# How to hide label on input-focus with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, input, label

I am trying to hide the label when I click inside an input field, but it just doesn't work and I cant figure out why on my own.

I tried to modify this example to suit my needs without any luck.: http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/07/creating-a-form-with-labels-inside-text-fields-using-jquery/

Please be as simple as possible, no nifty tricks needed here.

My code:
html:

```
fieldset id="fieldset1">
    <dl>
        <dt class="jform_name">
            <label id="jform_name-lbl" class=" required" for="jform_name">Wer sind Sie:</label>
        </dt>
        <dd class="jform_name">
            <input id="jform_name" class="required" type="text" aria-required="true" required="required" size="37" value="" name="jform[name]">
        </dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input#jform_name').focus(function(){
    $('label#jform_name-lbl').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/4LZv7/

Comment: #dafuq??? Okay thats interesting! Now why doesn't it work on my page? I will investigate...
Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Don't put tags in front of id's in selectors re: `input#jform_name` just use the id selector `#jform_name` as that will be faster

Comment: I assume the missing tag start on the `fieldset` is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't including jQuery in the HTML you posted, and although it's possible you haven't included the full HTML (please do this in the future), I think this is still worth mentioning as you seem to be new.

You'll need this in your html, preferably at the bottom, just above the `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, as Adrift mentioned, your displayed code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4LZv7/